# Why can't I catch the OOM exception?

Tags: qt, exception, try-catch, out-of-memory, qstringlist

I have a function that reads a large file to fill a QStringList. The program crashes probably because there is not enough memory because if I use a small file the program runs well. I try to debug the problem by catching the exception.

```
QStringList readlargefile(QString filename)
{
    QStringList result;
    QFile file(filename);
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        qDebug()<<"cannot open file: "<<filename;
        return result;
    }
    QTextStream in(&file);
    in.setCodec("UTF-8");
    QString line;

    while(in.readLineInto(&line))
    {
        if(!line.isEmpty())
            result<<line;
    }

    file.close();
    return result;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QStringList result;
    try
    {
        qDebug()<<"reading file";
        result=readlargefile("largefile.txt");
    }
    catch(...) {
        qFatal("got exception");
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
reading file
Killed
```

I cannot catch the exception, why?

Comment: What if you don't store the strings into the string list? Will the program run normally with the large file?

Comment: Which exception do you want to catch?

Comment: if it is the OOM the OS kills your program. [https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand016.html](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand016.html)

Comment: @ NgocMinhNguyen, if I don't store the string into the stringlist, the program runs normally with the large file without any problem.

Comment: @scopchanov I tried to catch the std::bad_alloc exception but could not catch it. Now I try to catch all exceptions, but still cannot catch any of them.

Comment: @rescherjm do you mean if kernel kills the process, no exception is generated?

Comment: Have you tried running it under a debugger?  At the very least that should give you the call stack at the point of the crash.

Comment: ***do you mean if kernel kills the process, no exception is generated?*** That is what I expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your program is aborted by OS it will not generate any exception. But you can setup a signal handler:

```
void signalHandler(int)
{
    //...
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    signal(SIGINT  , signalHandler);
    signal(SIGTERM , signalHandler);
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
    signal(SIGBREAK, signalHandler);
#endif
```

The reason you can't catch `std::bad_alloc` is because Qt probably uses a no-throw version of `::new`. Or `new` is OK but the Princess is in another castle.

There are two pitfalls you may stumble upon with your original problem  (crash).

**1. It can be a reallocating issue.**

When the array is filled up already, and you try to insert more, it allocates a new array and copies (moves) data from the previous one. So you end up having two big arrays until copying (moving) is done. If you know the exact number of strings ahead, you can try preallocating the array to ensure there will be no reallocations. Use `QList::reserve()` for that.

**2. Qt containers like QList and QVector can hold no more than 2GB of data.**

If `sizeof(QString)` is 8 bytes, there will be allowed no more than 2^28 items.

It will crash eventually if you try to store more. Try `std::vector` (with `reserve`) and check if it works.

After all, if your system doesn't have enough memory for the task - it doesn't have enough memory, and there is nothing you can do about it but to change your algorithm.

Comment: I install the signal handler for SIGINT, SIGTERM as you suggest, but cannot catch the signals and the output is the same, maybe the process is terminated by SIGKILL which cannot be caught. I use the stringlist.reserve function to reserve 4000000 items(> #line in the file) successfully before reading lines into it but the process is also killed. The large file is about 100MB so I think my program would consume about 200MB memory. My system is 512MB plus swap file so I think there is enough virtual memory for the process. Maybe the kernel always kills the process that consumes a lot of memory.

Comment: I am not clear about the mechanism of exceptions. Are all exception generated by some code in the program(either by my own code or by code in the libs the program is linked, using "throw xxx")? If so, it is unlike the mechanism of signals which can be generated by system or other processes then sent to the process. If so, does that mean before the process is killed by kernel, no code in the program throws an exception so I cannot catch any exception? But I can hardly think a divide-by-zero exception is thrown by some code in the program.

Comment: divide-by-zero and integer overflow are of special type of exception. 


`Stroustrup says, in "The Design and Evolution of C++" (Addison Wesley, 1994), "low-level events, such as arithmetic overflows and divide by zero, are assumed to be handled by a dedicated lower-level mechanism rather than by exceptions. This enables C++ to match the behaviour of other languages when it comes to arithmetic. It also avoids the problems that occur on heavily pipelined architectures where events such as divide by zero are asynchronous."`


On Windows, they are called structured exceptions

Comment: empty QString occupies 32 bytes. If you have 4000000 of them it's already 128.000.000 bytes _for empty strings_. I think you're running out of memory. Consider changing your algorithm. Say, you can calculate offsets to certaing strings inside your file and read them on demand. Or you can store unique strings only and have an array of indexes.